# How to display results from database in Sinatra using Sequel?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, sinatra, sequel

I have an SQLite3 database called *sk.db* with a table called *Sked* that displays a schedule of sports matches with a column *date*. I am simply trying to display today's matches. It appears as though the connection to the database is not working, though I do not get any errors.

I have tried looking through the Sequel documentation to no avail. How can I display results from an existing database in Sinatra?

**.rb**

```
require 'date'
require 'sequel'
require 'sinatra'

DB = Sequel.connect("sqlite://sk.db")

class Sked < Sequel::Model
end

schedule = DB.from(:sked)

get '/' do
  todaymatches = schedule.where(:date => Date.today)
  erb :games
end
```

**.erb**

```
 <h1>Games</h1>
 <p><%= @todaymatches %></p>
```

Comment: Try `@todaymatches = schedule.where(...)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I get: #<#:0x007f929439df68> in place of the data.

Comment: yeah, that's normal. That's what that object looks like as a string. If you expected to see team names and whatnot, then print them explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. How do I display all the matching rows? Right now I only get one displayed.

Comment: Loop over them with `.each`, for example

Comment: I've tried this but evidently I'm going wrong somewhere: `<p><%= @todaygames.each{|row| p row} %></p>`

Comment: yeah, should be more like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665279/why-is-this-rails-view-spitting-out-a-raw-array-at-the-end-of-an-each-do-loop?rq=1

Comment: I tried a couple variations on this but it doesn't seem to do the trick.  `<% @todaysgames.each do |t| %>
   <%= t %>
  <% end %>` I get No Method Error. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I got the erb code to work by changing the rb code to `schedule.all`. For some reason `@todaymatches` only contains one row when it should contain 5 or 6. Using `schedule.where` shouldn't `@todaymatches` contain all matching rows?

Comment: After including `@todaymatches.inspect` in the erb code, it appears to only get the first row, no matter the query I place inside `where(..)`... Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

.where doesn't actually retrieve data, but instead returns a dataset. Add an .all to actually retrieve the data

```
todaymatches = schedule.where(:date => Date.today).all
```